# Find the sum $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)$$

On their own, all three are divergent, so I thought the best way would be to rewrite it as:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}}\cdot \left(\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)=\frac{\left(\left(\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}\right)^2-n\right)}{\left(\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)}$$

But that doesn't really make anything simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sqrt{n+2}-2\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n=\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1}-(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n)$$ $$=\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n+1}}-\dfrac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}=F(n+1)-F(n)$$

where $F(m)=\dfrac1{\sqrt{m+1}+\sqrt m}$

Answer (score 0):

Render the summand as $(\sqrt{n+2}-\sqrt{n+1})-(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n})$ and use telescoping.  The difference between two consecutive square roots goes to zero as the arguments go to infinity.  You should be able to see the answer immediately.

Comment: sqrt(2)-1?  I think

Comment: Bull's eye.  :-)